# Recognition of Part Numbers in text

Tags: machine-learning

I am veteran programmer but an AI/ML newbie.

I have a large body of technical text sprinkled with part numbers. The part numbers don't follow a strict format that I can easily use a regular expression to recognize. I have a large collection of "labeled" data. Each entry is a short snippet of text "labeled" with the correct part numbers that are recognized inside it.

What is the best strategy to create such a recognition machine?

### EDIT - Clarification

So sorry, I live in my business domain and I assumed everyone knows what I was talking about.

Here are some examples of part numbers:

- `SAK-TC233LC-24F133F`
- `MAX1480BEPI+`
- `LM2676SX-5.0/NOPB`
- `PIC16F1708T-E/SS`
- `MT47H64M16NF-25E IT:M TR`
- `IS42S16800F-7TL-TR`
- `BSS110 (Q62702-S489)`
- `BSS209PW L6327`

A row is a line of text (usually the subject of an email) and can be extremely unstructured. Here are some subject line examples:

- `回复: Re: RFQ FROM IK STONE: MT47H64M16NF-25E IT:M TR 4000PCS`
- `Re: RE: Fwd: MKL16Z128VFT4 1300pcs RFQ`
- `Cancel: ORDER: STM32H743IGT6 IMPROVED PRICE`
- `PO#2923960045---PCF8577CT/3,118  1000pcs`
- `Re: Fw: Fwd: Requirements (China) of TXS0102DCTR from Shanghai QuiQun Capital Co., LTD`
- `回复：LM2675MX-ADJ/NOPB IMPROVED OFFER`

I have over 100000 correctly labeled subject lines, i.e. a subject line with the part numbers that are detected in it (can be 0 part numbers as well, not all subject lines contain part numbers)

Comment: Could you clarify what a "part number" is? Could also provide an example of your dataset? What is a row? What are the classes here, i.e. which possible "labels" can you assign to each input? How many examples (or samples) do you have in your dataset?

Comment: I added clarifications to the question, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: One possible way to solve this is to first remove everything that looks like an english word (along with its adjacent punctuation)